# Problemas con Graphics en C# VisualStudio

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy tratando de dibujar en C# con la clase graphics, por lo que creo un panel (al cual le seteo width: 500 y height: 300) y lo ejecuto imprimiendo por consola el largo y ancho de dicho panel y me imprime que es de 375x244. Porque pasa esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y el código donde "imprimes" los valores?

Comment: Esta abajo de la segunda foto, Ancho: 375 y LARGO: 244.

Comment: Me refiero al código en c#

Answer (score 0):

Su pregunta no es muy clara, pero si a lo que se refiere es:
**¿Por qué un panel cambia de tamaño en tiempo de ejecucion?**

Pueden existir varios factores, el formulario posee una propiedad llamada `AutoScaleMode` lo recomendable es asignar la propiedad como:

`this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;`.

Tambien debe asegurarse que el panel contenga la propiedad `Anchor` como:
`panel1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);` y la propiedad `AutoSize` como `panel1.AutoSize = false;`

Espero le sea de utilidad.